# Usage of SQL Server Transaction Log in Logging

Tags: sql-server, logging

Can I use Transaction Log File to show history of data changes? I want to report of data. If yes, How? I need logging changes in table records.

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of [DBMS' transaction log](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transaction_log) is to use it during failure recovery and is generally not accessible to DB users.

You should maintain your own audit tables on the primary data tables, write triggers on primary tables to populate these audit tables whenever the data changes and use the audit tables to generate reports about changes.